# Elastic beanstalk npm permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a react application on Elastic Beanstalk.

When I try to deploy my code the build fails and degrades back to the sample app.

Logs output suggests a permission issue:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/app/staging/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp'
```

I have tried adding an .npmrc file to my root directory containing

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

But that doesn't seem to solve it for me.

I also tried several .ebextensions solutions I have found and none of them seem to work for me.

I would love to get some help on this as I am currently stuck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I probably know why you get stuck. Alot of resources online supply you with old config files which only work on Amazon Linux; And you are probably now trying to build on Amazon Linux 2. A few months back I moved from Amazon linux to Amazon linux 2 and I aswell needed to rewrite alot of configuration files. I see two solutions:

1. Not sure if this is a solution for you but I never install dependencies on the server I host my application. You can install your dependencies before uploading it to elastic beanstalk. I utilize my jenkins server for this purpose (building, zipping and uploading a new version to Elastic Beanstalk)
2. If you want to continue on your current path I would understand that aswell; look into examples which supply you with predeploy and postdeploy hooks; An quick example I found is:

https://github.com/jakemmarsh/ebs-setup

With Amazon Linux 2 elastic beanstalk has moved alot of its configuration files towards a .platform folder where you put all you bash scripts which you want to run to configure your application